# Gaps in time series graphs

Tags: javascript, time-series, libgee

I am trying to generate a JavaScript code for use in Google Earth Engine which will allow me to calculate NDSI and with it generate a time series, however, this time series has gaps in the graph function. What am I doing wrong and how can I come up with a solution?

I have tried interpolating for the missing data but the graph remains the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.